# How to disable textbox when I check the ckeckbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to follow the textbook but the result won't disable the textbox in my site when I click on the checkbox

```
 <form action="#">
    Billing Address same as Shipping Address:
    <input type="checkbox" name="billingAdd" id="billingAdd">
    <br><br>
    Street Address
    <input type="text" id="street" name="street" class="baddr">
    <br><br>
    City:
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="baddr">
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()    {
        $("#billingAdd").click(function()   {
            if ($("#billingAdd").attr("checked") == "checked")  {
                $(".baddr").val("");
                $(".baddr").attr("disabled","disabled");
            } else if ($("#billingAdd").attr("checked") == undefined) {
                $(".baddr").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like so (you should use `prop()`, not `attr()`/`removeAttr()`):

```
$(document).ready(function()    {
    $("#billingAdd").click(function() {
        if (this.checked)  {
           $(".baddr").val("");
        }
        $(".baddr").prop("disabled", this.checked);
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/VAh8m/3/)

Comment: Really thank you for that, it works :). can you explain why my code didn't work?
(I follow the textbook "php, mysql, javascript and html for dummies - book3 chap5)

Comment: @user3527561 No worries - the book is probably fairly old - notice your code works in jQuery 1.6 ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/c66a8/)). Nowadays, instead of removing the attribute, we simply set the elements property to false/true etc :)